# Hibernate one to many association deletion

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

In a one to many bidirectional association with cascade enabled as all-delete-orphan in hibernate, is there any possibility ever hibernate try to delete child entity using foreign key column?
Its firing one extra query delete from child where foreign_key_col = parent_primary_key.

Comment: What do you mean by firing " extra query"? How do you expect the child records to be deleted once the corresponding master record is deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bidirectional relation,if you delete casacade in the parent entity.

You can remove the child from parent directly.

```java
//set parent as null
child.setParent(null)

//parent.children.iterater and remove it from the iterator.

//then save the parent.
save(parent)
```